# Python unittest: How to temporarily redirect stdout messages to a buffer and to test its content?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to capture messages sent to `stdout` (our `stderr`) temporarily during a test and assert if some string patterns occurred in these messages:

```
import unittest
class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_stdout(self):
        output = ""
        function_that_writes_to_stdout()
        # How to capture stdout in output temporarily?
        self.assertIn("some message", output)
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56045623), but the accepted answer suggests to capture messages sent to `stdout` for all test cases.

Yes, I know that it's not very smart to unittest messages sent to stdout. And yes, I also know that it'd be better to use `logging` in combination with [`assertLogs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs). Let's assume that both options are not available at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1.** The following worked for me:

```
import io
import unittest
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_stdout(self):
        buf = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(buf):
            print("foo!")
        self.assertIn("foo", buf.getvalue())
```

`buf.getvalue()` will contain the entire output, including `\n` characters.

**Solution 2.** To mimic the behavior of [`assertLogs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs), one can extend `unittest.TestCase` by a method `assertStdout` as follows.

```
class StdoutRedirectionContext():
    class ListIO():
        def __init__(self):
            # Container for messages sent to stdout.
            self.output = []
        def write(self, s):
            # Filter empty strings or naked newline characters.
            if s in ("\n", ""): return
            self.output.append(s)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._buf = self.ListIO()
        self._ctx = redirect_stdout(self._buf)
        self._ctx.__enter__()
        return self._buf

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self._ctx.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertStdout(self):
        return StdoutRedirectionContext()
```

Here, `StdoutRedirectionContext` acts a context manager, and the single messages will be collected in the  `output` list. The extended `TestCase` can be used as follows to assert messages on stdout:

```
class AnotherTest(TestCase):
    def test_stdout(self):
        with self.assertStdout() as cm:
            print("foo!")
            print("bar!")
        self.assertIn("foo!", cm.output)
        self.assertIn("baz!", cm.output)
```

The above yields the following output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_stdout (__main__.AnotherTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "executor_test.py", line 440, in test_stdout
    self.assertIn("baz!", cm.output)
AssertionError: 'baz!' not found in ['foo!', 'bar!']
```