# Is there a way to print directly to console during a unittest in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest

In python unittests, the unit test captures stdout so prints only occur after the test is finished. I want a way to forcefully bypass these and log specific messages to the console without completely disabling this functionality. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using pytest?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049216/3717691

Comment: @frankfalse I am just running the code in PyCharm, but it's basically just QoL during long tests so I can actually see if something is happening

Comment: @Jeppe I have attempted to add a buffer as described there while leaving out the ontextlib.redirect_stdout,  but it doesn't appear to work :/

Comment: @Henry C My only suggestion in this moment is: if you use pytest exists the option `-s` which is used to suppress the `Captured stdout call`, but I don't know if it is useful for you. Please add code.

Comment: If your problem is related to PyCharm, perhaps check this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505